# INSERT Query Syntax Error in PHP and MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I am not able to insert id and name in myTable MySQL table by using following PHP syntax. id is integer field and name is varchar field.

```
$query="INSERT INTO myTable (id, name) VALUES (".$_SESSION["id"].", ".$_SESSION["name"].");";
```

Is there something wrong with above syntax? As per me its right because if insert hardcoded values, those are inserted fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you need to use single quotes for name

```
$query="INSERT INTO myTable (id, name) VALUES (" . $_SESSION["id"] . ", '" . $_SESSION["name"]."');";
```

Also, **please try not to contstruct the queries by hand using string concatenation/substitution**. It can be dangerous if your `$_SESSION` (somehow) contains content that can manipulate queries completely.

Read about SQL Injection, and [what PHP offers.](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php)

Answer (score 2):

Put the string value inside quotes:

```
$query="INSERT INTO myTable (id, name) VALUES (".$_SESSION["id"].", '".$_SESSION["name"]."');";
```

Answer (score 2):

String should be enclosed in quotes

```
 $query="INSERT INTO myTable (id, name) VALUES (".$_SESSION["id"].", '".$_SESSION["name"]."');";
```

Comment: okay, I forgot put single quotes around name field. Thanks, its working now.

Answer (score 1):

`name` is a reserved word.  Put backticks around it.  Also, you need quotes around your name variable (and the id, if it is not an integer).

Your query should look like this:

```
$query="INSERT INTO myTable (id, `name`) VALUES (".$_SESSION["id"].", '".$_SESSION["name"]."')";
```

Comment: I don't really think so:  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html

Comment: Hmm... You're right.  It is formatted like one in MySQL Workbench, so I guess I just assumed it was.  I always surround my column names with backticks, anyway, to be safe; I spent many hours debugging a column named `desc` when I was first starting out...

Comment: @EdCottrell - sorry, I was using ename field and in questions I put name field.

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
$query="INSERT INTO myTable (id, name) VALUES ({$_SESSION["id"]},'{$_SESSION["name"]}');";
```